# Python pandas - grouping and plotting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

In `df1` I have columns for Line, Generation, ID, and Sex.

I want to count matching occurrences in `df2` of the remaining columns for each row.

The desired result would look like:

- Line A, Generation 2020A, has a total of `1` row for row `['A','A','A','A']` in `df2`.
- Line B, Generation 2020B, has a total of `2` rows for row `['A','C','T','G']` in `df2`.

`df1`

| Line | ID | Sex | Generation | SNP-1 | SNP-2 | SNP-3 | SNP-4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | F | 2020A | A | A | A | A |
| B | 2 | F | 2020B | A | C | T | G |
| B | 3 | F | 2020B | A | C | T | G |

`df2`

| SNP-1 | SNP-2 | SNP-3 | SNP-4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | A | A |
| A | C | T | G |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `merge` and then do `value_counts` to achieve this.

```
import pandas as pd    
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['A','2020A',   'A',    'A',    'A',    'A'], ['B','2020B', 'A',    'C',    'T',    'G'],['B','2020B',  'A',    'C',    'T',    'G']], columns= ['Line','Generation','SNP-1',   'SNP-2',    'SNP-3',    'SNP-4'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([['A',   'A',    'A',    'A'],['A',  'C',    'T',    'G']], columns=['SNP-1',    'SNP-2',    'SNP-3',    'SNP-4'])

df_merge = df1.merge(df2, on=['SNP-1',  'SNP-2',    'SNP-3',    'SNP-4'])
print(df_merge)

print('\n', df_merge.value_counts(['Line', 'Generation']))
```

**Output:**

```
  Line Generation SNP-1 SNP-2 SNP-3 SNP-4
0    A      2020A     A     A     A     A
1    B      2020B     A     C     T     G
2    B      2020B     A     C     T     G

 Line  Generation
B     2020B         2
A     2020A         1
dtype: int64
```